# Showing one definition of semiring implies the other (or maybe are equivalent?)

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

There are two definitions of a semiring that I have seen.

Let $X$ be a set, and $S$ be a set of subsets of $X$. Then $S$ is a semiring if and only if:

- $\varnothing \in S$
- $A, B \in S \implies A \cap B \in S$
- If $A, B \in S$, there are sets $A_1, \dots, A_n \in S$ which are pairwise disjoint and satisfy $A \setminus B = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i$.

Another definition I've seen is identical for the first two conditions above, but changes the third condition above to:

- If $A, A^{\prime} \in S$ with $A^{\prime} \subset A$, there are sets $A_1, \dots, A_n \in S$ which are pairwise disjoint and are disjoint from $A^{\prime}$, satisfying $A = A^{\prime} \cup \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i\right)$.

Are these definitions equivalent? If so, how? **Or at the very least, does the second definition imply the first definition?**

I thought there might be a trick perhaps considering $A, B \in S$, let $A^{\prime} = A \setminus B \subset A$. But we can't do anything with this unless we know $A^{\prime} \in S$. How would we know? I'm not sure.

Comment: [They are equivalent.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Definitions_of_Semiring_of_Sets) The trick was using the intersection instead of set difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they’re equivalent. Assume the first definition, and let $A,A'\in S$ with $A'\subseteq A$. Then $A\setminus A'=\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i$ for some pairwise disjoint sets $A_i\in S$. Clearly the sets $A_i$ are disjoint from $A'$, and $A=A'\cup\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i$.

Now assume the second definition, and let $A,B\in S$. Let $A'=A\cap B$; $A'\in S$, so $A=A'\cup\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i$ for some pairwise disjoint set $A_i\in S$ that are all disjoint from $A'$, and $A\setminus B=A\setminus A'=\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i$.